# How to release resources in Spring bean?

Tags: java, spring

Consider this example

```
@Component
class MyExpensiveClass {
  private DB db;
}
```

When `Spring` application instantiates, a bean `myExpensiveClass` is created.

Now if I am shutting down the applicationContext, I would like to release the handle to `db`.

Is there a way I can do that in Spring? like implementing a method and `Spring` calls it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using xml configuration, you can register an init and destroy method

```
<bean id="customerService"class="com.mkyong.customer.services.CustomerService" 
          init-method="initIt" destroy-method="cleanUp">
```

If you are using annotations only

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean(initMethodName="init")
    public Foo foo() {
        return new Foo();
    }
    @Bean(destroyMethodName="cleanup")
    public Bar bar() {
        return new Bar();
    }
}
```

[Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html)